# Is my interpretation of the sentence right?

Tags: sentence-meaning, grammaticality

I'll talk to you in thirty minutes, be here then.

Does the above sentence mean **The speaker wants to talk to someone in thirty minutes, and wants them to be present where the talk is supposed to take place?**

And is the given sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: Yes, but those are actually two sentences and should be separated with a semicolon. While it is otherwise grammatically OK, it is rather demanding. Even if you are the person's supervisor, it would be better to write something like this: **"I'll talk to you in thirty minutes; please be here then or let me know if you cannot make it. If the latter, please suggest another time for us to meet. Thank you."**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.

> The speaker wants to talk to someone in thirty minutes, and wants them
>   to be present where the talk is supposed to take place *[added: **at the time when the talk is supposed to take place**]*?

@MarkHubbard  Imagine this is a father and son situation :)

Comment: The speaker says he wants the other person to be ***here***, which leads to the *contextually implicit* assertion that the talk will take place ***where the speaker is*** when he makes the statement. And ***then*** simply refers back to ***in 30 minutes [time]*** ("then" = 30m later than when he makes the statement).